# How to map a nested value to a property using Jackson annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I'm making a call to an API that responds with the following JSON for a product:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "The Best Product",
  "brand": {
     "id": 234,
     "name": "ACME Products"
  }
}
```

I'm able to map the product id and name just fine using Jackson annotations:

```
public class ProductTest {
    private int productId;
    private String productName, brandName;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }
}
```

And then using the fromJson method to create the product:

```
  JsonNode apiResponse = api.getResponse();
  Product product = Json.fromJson(apiResponse, Product.class);
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to grab the brand name, which is a nested property. I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
    @JsonProperty("brand.name")
    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }
```

But of course it didn't. Is there an easy way to accomplish what I want using annotations?

> The actual JSON response I'm trying to parse is very complex, and I don't want to have to create an entire new class for every sub-node, even though I only need a single field.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath — Spring uses it under the hood as well. For example, in their org.springframework.data.web.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can achieve this like that:

```
String brandName;

@JsonProperty("brand")
private void unpackNameFromNestedObject(Map<String, String> brand) {
    brandName = brand.get("name");
}
```

Comment: How about three levels deep?

Comment: @Robin Wouldn't that work?

```this.abbreviation = ((Map<String, Object>)portalCharacteristics.get("icon")).get("ticker").toString();
```

Comment: same method can be used for unpacking multiple values as well... unpackValuesFromNestedBrand - thanks

Comment: For three levels use JsonNode directly. Map becomes too cumbersome:
`void unpackName(JsonNode company) { name = company.get("division").get("brand").get("name).asText(); }`

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak - What is the value of JsonProperty annotation when using JsonNode for multi-level mappings?

Comment: @AndyDufresne, it is the same as the root of the sub-object you are interested in. In my example it would be the name of the property that holds the object containing `division`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for immutable objects or `records`.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I handled this problem:

`Brand` class:

```
package org.answer.entity;

public class Brand {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Brand() {

    }

    //accessors and mutators
}
```

`Product` class:

```
package org.answer.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

public class Product {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Brand brand;

    private String brandName;

    public Product(){}

    @JsonGetter("brandName")
    protected String getBrandName() {
        if (brand != null)
            brandName = brand.getName();
        return brandName;
    }

    @JsonSetter("brandName")
    protected void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        if (brandName != null) {
            brand = new Brand();
            brand.setName(brandName);
        }
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

//other accessors and mutators
}
```

Here, the `brand` instance will be ignored by `Jackson` during `serialization` and `deserialization`, since it is annotated with `@JsonIgnore`.

`Jackson` will use the method annotated with `@JsonGetter` for `serialization` of java object into `JSON` format. So, the `brandName` is set with `brand.getName()`.

Similarly, `Jackson` will use the method annotated with `@JsonSetter` for `deserialization` of `JSON` format into java object. In this scenario, you will have to instantiate the `brand` object yourself and set its `name` property from `brandName`.

You can use `@Transient` persistence annotation with `brandName`, if you want it to be ignored by persistence provider.

Answer (score 7):

You can use JsonPath-expressions to map nested properties. I don't think there's any official support (see [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/76) issue), but there's an unofficial implementation here: https://github.com/elasticpath/json-unmarshaller

Answer (score 5):

The best is to use setter methods:

JSON:

```
...
 "coordinates": {
               "lat": 34.018721,
               "lng": -118.489090
             }
...
```

setter method for lat or lng will look like:

```
 @JsonProperty("coordinates")
    public void setLng(Map<String, String> coordinates) {
        this.lng = (Float.parseFloat(coordinates.get("lng")));
 }
```

if you need to read both (as you normally would do) then use a custom method

```
@JsonProperty("coordinates")
public void setLatLng(Map<String, String> coordinates){
    this.lat = (Float.parseFloat(coordinates.get("lat")));
    this.lng = (Float.parseFloat(coordinates.get("lng")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to  **solve any** issue related to JSON nested mapping.

First store your response as a **Map**:

```
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response =
        restTemplate.exchange(
            requestUri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            buildAuthHeader(),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
            });
```

Now you can read **any nested value in your JSON tree**. For example:

```
response.getBody().get("content").get(0).get("terminal")
```

In this case, my JSON is:

```
{
"page": 0,
"total_pages": 1,
"total_elements": 2,
"content": [
    {
        "merchant": "000405",
        "terminal": "38010101",
        "status": "Para ser instalada", 
....
```

Comment: That cant work without casting to `Map<String, Object>` after each `get("node")`

Comment: That is in case you need to store the whole map in a variable. If you call `.get("terminal")` inline, you just get the value in string "38010101"

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I haven't seen recommended and required the least amount of rewrite for me (See the **UPDATE**): [Spring boot @JsonProperty to map nested object through parent.child path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042266/spring-boot-jsonproperty-to-map-nested-object-through-parent-child-path)

Answer (score -1):

Just use @JsonUnwrapped:

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-unwrapped.html

This puts the child objects in the parent.

Comment: `@JsonUnwrapped` maps a nested object structure to a flat json; this question is about the opposite: a nested json to a flat object.

Answer (score -6):

To make it simple ..I have written the code ...most of it is self explanatory.

`Main Method`

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class LOGIC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String DATA = "{\r\n" + 
                "  \"id\": 123,\r\n" + 
                "  \"name\": \"The Best Product\",\r\n" + 
                "  \"brand\": {\r\n" + 
                "     \"id\": 234,\r\n" + 
                "     \"name\": \"ACME Products\"\r\n" + 
                "  }\r\n" + 
                "}";

        ProductTest productTest = objectMapper.readValue(DATA, ProductTest.class);
        System.out.println(productTest.toString());

    }

}
```

`Class ProductTest`

```
package com.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ProductTest {

    private int productId;
    private String productName;
    private BrandName brandName;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("brand")
    public BrandName getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }
    public void setBrandName(BrandName brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductTest [productId=" + productId + ", productName=" + productName + ", brandName=" + brandName
                + "]";
    }



}
```

`Class BrandName`

```
package com.test;

public class BrandName {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BrandName [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }




}
```

`OUTPUT`

```
ProductTest [productId=123, productName=The Best Product, brandName=BrandName [id=234, name=ACME Products]]
```

Comment: This works, but I'm trying to find a solution where I don't have to create a new class for every node even if I only need one field.

Answer (score -8):

Hi here is the **complete working code.**

**//JUNIT TEST CLASS**

public class sof {

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Brand b = new Brand();
    b.id=1;
    b.name="RIZZE";

    Product p = new Product();
    p.brand=b;
    p.id=12;
    p.name="bigdata";


    //mapper
    ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
    o.registerSubtypes(Brand.class);
    o.registerSubtypes(Product.class);
    o.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String json=null;
    try {
        json = o.writeValueAsString(p);
        assertTrue(json!=null);
        logger.info(json);

        Product p2;
        try {
            p2 = o.readValue(json, Product.class);
            assertTrue(p2!=null);
            assertTrue(p2.id== p.id);
            assertTrue(p2.name.compareTo(p.name)==0);
            assertTrue(p2.brand.id==p.brand.id);
            logger.info("SUCCESS");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.toString());
        }




    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.toString());
    }


}
}




**// Product.class**
    public class Product {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    @JsonProperty("brand") //not necessary ... but written
    protected Brand brand;

}

    **//Brand class**
    public class Brand {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;     
}
```

**//Console.log of junit testcase**

```
2016-05-03 15:21:42 396 INFO  {"id":12,"name":"bigdata","brand":{"id":1,"name":"RIZZE"}} / MReloadDB:40 
2016-05-03 15:21:42 397 INFO  SUCCESS / MReloadDB:49
```

Complete gist : https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/7c94d4b36a809d4acf2f188f204a8058

Comment: The actual JSON response I'm trying to map is very complex. It has a lot of nodes and subnodes, and creating a class for each would be very painful, even more so when in most cases I only need a single field from a set of triple nested nodes. Is there not a way to just get the single field without having to create a ton of new classes?

Comment: open a new sof ticket and share it with me, I can help you on this. Share the json struture you want to map please. :)