# How to get property not only from root level

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some troubles with parsing JSON using Jackson library

```json
{
    "userName": "blablabla@gmail.com",
        "ID": {
            "uniqueID": "1234567"
        }
}
```

This is the part of the JSON, and my model is:

```java
public class UserIdAndMail {
    @JsonProperty("uniqueID")
    private String id;

    
    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String mail;

    public UserIdAndMail(String id, String mail) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public UserIdAndMail() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

`'uniqueID'` becomes `null` value when I try to parse the JSON to object. I have no idea how to get this field without creating an additional class `"ID"`. Can there be a simpler solution to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of - [How to map a nested value to a property using Jackson annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010891/how-to-map-a-nested-value-to-a-property-using-jackson-annotations)

```
String id;

@JsonProperty("ID")
private void unpackNameFromNestedObject(Map<String, String> id) {
    this.id= id.get("uniqueID");
}
```