# how to transform properly a json to object where the key is actually a changing value?

Tags: java, json

I am wondering how to do this transformation.

I normally transform from json to Java objects like this:

```
{
    "detail" : 
        {
            "student": {
                "name" : "John Doe",
                "age" : 31
            }
        }

}
```

So I can easily create a Java object called student and do something like this

```
public class Student {
String name;
int age;

public Student(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

But now I am facing this issue...

I am getting a JSON like this:

```
{
       "detail" : 
        {
            "123456789": {
                "name" : "John Doe",
                "age" : 31
            }
        }

}
```

Where **123456789** is in this case, the "student" ...

Is there anyway I can design an object to parse from **JSON** to my **java object?** I have no idea how to do this trick...

Comment: Maybe first transform it into a `Map` and then do your own mapping, or a complete other way: *Where are you getting that data from*? Can you influence what is done to the JSON before it is sent to you?

Comment: `name` and `age` are still the properties you look for. `@JsonProperty` is not a class-level annotation, so how do you go about transforming this normally? It should just be the same.

Comment: thanks @Lino, any concrete example ?

Comment: thanks @mumpitz, but I actually want to get that ID as well

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010891/how-to-map-a-nested-value-to-a-property-using-jackson-annotations) helps?

Comment: I added more details if that helps...

Comment: I assumed that you have a `Detail` class which has `Student` field?

Comment: yes, I named it "Student" but when using the constructor with @JsonProperty it doesnt not work

Answer (score 3):

May be this little example helps?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "    {\n" +
            "        \"123456789\": {\n" +
            "            \"name\" : \"John Doe\",\n" +
            "            \"age\" : 31\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<Long, Student> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<Long, Student>>() {
        });
    }

    public static class Student {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, but I guess OP is looking for a way with annotation usage.