# Spring boot @JsonProperty to map nested object through parent.child path

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, annotations, json-annotation

I have the following Data structure coming to my server through an Http call

```json
person {
  name: "xyz",
  age: 30,
  status: {
    cd: "M",
    desc: "Married"
  }
}
```

Then I have the following entity class

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class Person {
  private String name;

  private int age;

  @JsonProperty("status.cd")
  private String status_cd;

  @JsonProperty("status/desc")
  private String status_desc;
}
```

Either way I try I'm not able to get spring boot to match the json property text (these two values are always null)... is that doable & if so, how?

the final JSON I need to be produced is the following

```json
{
  name: "XYZ",
  age: 30,
  status_cd: "M",     // <-- Child attached to parent (flattened)
  status_desc: "Married"  // <-- Child attached to parent (flattened)
}
```

So basically I need to attach my child info to the parent.

**UPDATE**
I was able to get one of the properties flattened with the parent by using a custom JsonDeserializer as follows

```java
public class nameDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
  @Overrde
  public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    PersonStatus st = p.valueAs(PersonStatus.class)
    return st.getStatusCd();
}
```

This works for only one property set with *@JsonDeserialize(using = nameDeserializre.class)* per class.... once I attach two deserializers to two properties, I start getting errors about json exceptions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public class Person {
  private String name;

  private int age;

 private Status status;
 
 //your getter setter
}

public class Status {

      private String cd;

      private String desc;
      
      // getter setter
      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that will give me nested json. while what I need is to flatten out my json into one parent. _please see m updates_ I explained my final json needed & some updates.

Comment: Try this one, this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010891/how-to-map-a-nested-value-to-a-property-using-jackson-annotations