# How to map a nested value to a property using @JsonAlias annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I need to get the **Country Name** from the nested object by **@JsonAlias** annotation on Java, Spring Boot project.

**@JsonAlias** is working properly for **name** field. But, not work on nested or child objects this approach.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    @JsonAlias("fullName")
    private String name;
    @JsonAlias("presentAddress.country.name")
    private String presentAddressCountryName;
    @JsonAlias("permanentAddress.country.name")
    private String permanentAddressCountryName;
}


String jsonString = """ 
{
  "id": 1,
  "fullName": "Md. Badrul Alam",
  "presentAddress": {
    "id": 1,
    "location": "Dhaka",
    "country": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bangladesh"
    }
  },
  "permanentAddress": {
    "id": 1,
    "location": "Jashore",
    "country": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pakistan"
    }
  }
}
"""

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Student student = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Student.class);
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010891/how-to-map-a-nested-value-to-a-property-using-jackson-annotations

Also https://devissuefixer.com/questions/how-to-map-a-nested-value-to-a-property-using-jackson-annotations

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already see the above references. 
If you have the solution then share us. - Scary Wombat

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonAlias` is designed for aliasing field names, not for deep nesting within JSON objects. To handle nested properties, you can use custom deserialization logic with Jackson's `@JsonDeserialize` annotation and a custom deserializer.

Comment: Can you please share the references?

Comment: Hello @Badrul, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042266/spring-boot-jsonproperty-to-map-nested-object-through-parent-child-path).