# XML Mapper to Pojo - Only Subelements?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xmlmapper

i want to deserialize XML to a Java Pojo, but i dont need all elements and i want to avoid creating boilerplate-wrapper classes just to get some subelements

The XML looks like this

```
<a>
  <b>NotInterestingValue</b>
  <c>
    <d>InterestingValue</d> 
    <e>InterestingValue</e>
  </c>
</a>
```

```
I created A.class {

   String b;
   C c;
}


class C {
  String d;
  String e;
}
```

I created a XML-Mapper like this:

`new XmlMapper(new JacksonXmlModule().readValue("xml-file", A.class)`

--> This works. But is it possible to deserialize the XML only with C?

e.g.
`new XmlMapper(new JacksonXmlModule().readValue("xml-file", C.class)` 
--> Doesnt work right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383076/15925714

-->

```
class C {
  String d;
  String e;

  @JsonProperty("c")
    private void unpackNameFromNestedObject(Map<String, String> c) {
        d= c.get("d");
        d= c.get("e");
    }
}
```